# Internal machine responds to different IP that its internet connection IP

Tags: dns, nslookup

I have a website running on AWS with the domain using *Route 53* for the DNS.

I used to have an *A record* (`dev.talkingcouch.uk`) pointing to my development machine and it worked fine. Today I find that my machine is responding to a different IP than is listed by tools such as *whatsmyip.org*.

My development webserver responds to the address `169.254.2.144` but my external IP address is `2.29.52.188`. Hence a webhook that I am developing cannot receive information from an external web server.

**I have disabled the *VirtualBox* adapter which reported as being at `169.254.2.144` and rebooted but the problem persists.**

There is no PTR record for either IP address acording to *mxtoolbox.com*.

Route 53 record:
`dev.example.uk. A 2.29.52.188`

whatsmyip.org
`2.29.52.188`

`ipconfig /all` gives:

```
Ethernet adapter Ethernet:
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . :        
fe80::ac13:8f80:5274:8efd%14(Preferred)
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.121(Preferred)
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0

Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:
Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.2.144(Tentative)
```

`nslookup dev.talkingcouch.uk` gives:

```
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    dev.talkingcouch.uk
Address:  2.29.52.188
```

I'm a bit stuck as I am a web developer and don't have much experience in networking.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed a strange problem. One way to overcome it is to create an ELB and register your ec2 instance in it. Then point your route53 record to the CNAME of the ELB. 
This is also a more trustworthy way of managing DNS records as the IP of the machine can change (unless you use an elastic IP for your EC2 instance) and the ELB cname will remain constant.